# Calculate all combinations and "different enough"

Tags: combinations

I am doing a bit of research on randomized avatar creation and I want to calculate all the possible combinations, knowing that are available

2 base models (male, female)
8 background
43 clothes
6 earring
23 eyes
19 fur
36 hat
33 mouth

Also I would like to know how many unique combinations are there and for unique we mean an avatar that has at least 3 different traits (i.e. two avatars that are exactly the same apart from just the background, is not considered unique).

I have approached the first question just multiplying all the traits but I am not sure if it is correct. For the second question I couldn't come up with the right approach... Thanks!

Comment: Please show your work, which makes it easier for readers to assess whether or not your approach is correct.

Comment: The uniqueness, as you defined it, is not an equivalence relation. If we have three avatars $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, it is possible that $Y$ differs by three traits from $X$, $Z$ differs by three traits from $Y$, and $Z$ does not differ by at least three traits from $X$ - it is still possible while $X \neq Z$. Therefore, we cannot define an equivalence class for an element, and we specifically cannot calculate the 'total' number of unique avatars. What we can do, is find the maximal set containing pairwise different avatars and containing a specified prior avatar $X_{0}$.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski fair point. I think that maximal set containing pairwise different avatars is a good enough approximation for what I have to achieve. How would I approach that?